# web-routes-boomerang with simple algebraic data type

Tags: haskell, routes, boomerang

I'm a little mixed up about how to properly use boomerang to generate URLs. I have the following:

```
data State =
  AK | AL | AR | AZ | CA ... WY

data Sitemap
    = Home
    | State State
    | Place State String
      deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Data, Typeable)

$(derivePrinterParsers ''Sitemap)

sitemap ∷ Router Sitemap
sitemap =
    (  rHome
    <> rState . state
    <> rPlace . (state </> anyString)
    )

state :: PrinterParser StringsError [String] o (State :- o)
state = xmaph read (Just . show) anyString
```

This seems to work, but when I compare my implementation of `state` with the one in the documentation for `articleId`, they seem to be working in opposite fashions:

```
articleId :: Router ArticleId
articleId = xmaph ArticleId (Just . unArticleId) int
```

The types are totally different and look like they're going in opposite directions, but my `sitemap` works and the app correctly handles URLs. I think it should look more like this:

```
maybeState :: String → Maybe State
maybeState stateString = case reads stateString of
                     [(state, "")] -> Just state
                     _             -> Nothing

stateR :: Router State
stateR = xpure show maybeState
```

This doesn't type-check, but even substituting `undefined` for its definition, in `sitemap` above, `rState . stateR` would work, but `rPlace . (stateR </> anyString)` doesn't.

Seems like this would come up often enough there's probably a library function to take care of this for me, but I didn't see one.

**Edit**: here are some of the type errors I get:

For `state = xpure show maybeState`:

```
Main.hs:56:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `State :- ()'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: () -> State :- ()
      Actual type: () -> String
    In the first argument of `xpure', namely `show'
    In the expression: xpure show maybeState
```

For `state = undefined :: Router State` (this error is in the `sitemap` definition):

```
Main.hs:45:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `String :- ()' with actual type `()'
    Expected type: PrinterParser
                     StringsError [String] () (State :- (String :- ()))
      Actual type: Router State
    In the first argument of `(</>)', namely `state'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(state </> anyString)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types look different because you use of state in the `rPlace` line requires a more general type signature than the `Router` type alias permits. (Your code is fine. But perhaps we should offer a more general alias in boomerang though..)

If you remove the rPlace line you can change the type signature of state to:

```
state :: Router State
state = xmaph read (Just . show) anyString
```

If you look more closely, I think you will see that `state` and `articleId` actually do go the same direction.

```
articleId :: Router ArticleId
articleId = xmaph ArticleId (Just . unArticleId) int
```

The third argument of `xmaph` specifies how to parse some underlying value. In the case of `articleId` it parses an `int` and for `state` it parses `anyString`.

The first argument of `xmaph` specifies how to convert that value to the desired return type. In `articleId` we simple apply the `ArticleId` constructor. In `state` we apply the `read` function. But in both cases we are going from the underlying value to the desired return type:

```
ArticleId :: Int    -> ArticleId
read      :: String -> State
```

The second argument to `xmaph` specifies how to convert the return type back to the underlying value.

```
show        :: State     -> String
unArticleId :: ArticleId -> Int
```

That said, we should not actually be using 'read' here anyway because 'read' could potentially fail and through an error. It is intended that the first argument to xmaph will be a total function.

I uploaded boomerang 1.3.1 which adds a new combinator to the `Strings` module named `readshow`. This function uses the Read and Show instances correctly. Unfortunately, error reporting is a bit sloppy since when `reads` fails it tells us nothing about why or where it failed. But it's better than nothing :)

Using that you could now write:

```
state :: PrinterParser StringsError [String] o (State :- o)
state = readshow
```

if we supply an invalid state we now get:

```
> parseStrings sitemap ["AZ"]
Right (State AZ)
> parseStrings sitemap ["FOEU"]
Left parse error at (0, 0): unexpected FOEU; decoding using 'read' failed.
```

Comment: What's surprising to me, I guess, is that the conversion from string to State is what can fail, not the conversion from State to string. I feel a bit dirty using `read`--does boomerang handle the possibility of read throwing an exception for me? Should I pull two characters instead of a whole string?

Comment: Yeah, you actually shouldn't be using read there at all. I added a new readshow combinator that does what you want. It is intended that the first argument to xmaph should always succeed (aka, be a total function).

Though perhaps the first argument to`xmaph` should be a `Maybe/Either` function. For example, `articleId` might want to fail if the int is negative.. I'll have to think about that more.

The argument against it is that xmaph is supposed to be like a bidirectional version of fmap, and fmap is simply `a -> b`. But then that does not explain why we have `(b -> Maybe a)`.